# Drupal Custom Module: How to Throw error When User Not select Checked box

Tags: php, drupal, module

I am developing a Drupal module. I have a file type to upload PDFs and a checked box that must be checked when user uploads a PDF, and if the user uploads a PDF but has not checked the check box an error is thrown and it goes back to the 'add content' form and highlights the check box. I have hooked `hook_nodeapi()` to check whether checkbox is checked or not. Now how can I throw an error to go back to the 'add content' form and highlight the checkbox?

Comment: Consider posting some of the relevant code that you're written so that people can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. I have coded as follows.

```
    if(isset($node->field_wp_attachment[0][filename])){
    $upload_pdf = $node->field_wp_attachment[0][filename];
    if(!isset($node->field_private[0][value])){
    form_set_error('field_private', t('Must Checked the Private.'),$reset = TRUE);
    drupal_goto($_GET['q']);
    }
    }
```